# Can I custom the process for 'Publish' button in Publish dialog in properties-local.xml?

Tags: orbeon

In document I see that we can custom the flow in properties-local.xml, but it is only available for Publish button outside (not publish button in dialog)

The flow I intend to do:

1. In Form builder, user click publish
2. Publish dialog showed, user click publish button in dialog.
3. Then it will call api from my server to send info.

In properties-local.xml, I modified inside this part:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.publish.orbeon.builder"> </property>
```

with this code:

```xml
<!-- show publish dialog -->
    xf:show(
            dialog = "fb-publish-dialog",
            app    = "{xxf:instance('fb-form-instance')/xh:head/xf:model[@id = 'fr-form-model']/xf:instance[@id = 'fr-form-metadata']/*/application-name}",
            form   = "{xxf:instance('fb-form-instance')/xh:head/xf:model[@id = 'fr-form-model']/xf:instance[@id = 'fr-form-metadata']/*/form-name}"
            )

<!-- expect when user click publish button in dialog will execute this code -->    
    then save
    then send(
         uri = "http://localhost:8000/api/getFormBuilderInfo",
         replace = "all"
         method = "POST",
         content = "xml")
```

The problem I don't know how to hook into publish button in dialog. Because  I want to make sure that it has stored in orbeon database in order to creating new in form runner with appName and formName (which I get through api: http://localhost:8000/api/getFormBuilderInfo).

Comment: I think you're correct, you could override the process that opens the dialog, after that the codes doesn't go through processes. But there might be some other way to do this. What information would you like to pass to your own API? And what does your API do?

Comment: Hi @avernet, I updated my question with code. My purpose is when user click publish button in dialog then it will send appName, formName and form version in form builder so that I can use that to create url like: localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/appName/formName/new

Comment: Thank you for the update, but I am unclear as to what do you mean by "I can use that to create url like: localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/appName/formName/new". When you publish a form, that form is automatically available at the URL you mentioned, and you shouldn't need to do anything else for that. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Thanks for your response @avernet, because user only open a new form in Form Runner from my web app (admin will create form in Form Builder). Therefore, is there any way I can hook my code after clicking submit button in the dialog?

Comment: I am still unclear as to *what* the code you would like to run on publish does. However, currently, there is no way for you to hook code running *after* the form is published. You could make this work using the `publish` process, and I am going into more details about this in my answer below, but as you can see, this technique can be quite convoluted. Hence me asking what your code would need to do, as there may (or may not) be another way to achieve that result.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, it isn't possible to invoke code after the form is published.

As a workaround, you could hook your code in the `publish` process, but this process runs before the form is being published, specifically before the Form Builder user is presented with a dialog asking them for a confirmation to publish the form. So, there will be delay between the time your code is invoked and the time the form is actually published, and of course there is a chance the user closes the dialog without going ahead with the publication of the form.

So, in practice, to use this workaround, you would need to apply some kind of heuristic, like "when your code is invoked, register some a listener to run, say in 5 minutes; when that time has passed, check if the form was actually published, and if so do the action that you needed to perform".